# How does Cisco IOS ACL established flag work

Tags: cisco, tcp, access-control-list, ios

You can permit outgoing packets, but then you need to permit the responses. One way is to permit any packet that is a followup to an established connection.

```
access-list ??? permit tcp any any established
```

But how does this work? Is checking `established` enough on a NAT config? I wonder whether I should create a specific locked down rule for every response packet group for example, I might have this for outgoing. (access list for Vlan1 IN)

```
access-list ??? permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 gt 1023 any eq www
```

and this for the response. (access list for FastEthernet4 IN)

```
access-list ??? permit tcp any eq www --WAN IP-- gt 1023 established
```

Is there better security in adding one `permit` `established` rule for every `permit` outgoing rule? Or am I just reducing performance when I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Given a Vlan1 inside and Fa4 outside I gather you are working on an 8xx series?

Instead of working through `established` use the IOS Firewall's Context Based Access Control function, or CBAC.

With a `deny ip any any` or equivalent on an outside interface -- as you have stated, there needs to exist some way to permit legitimate traffic initiated from inside -> outside to get back in without resorting to vulgar language or a `permit ip any any`.  `established` is one method, but a rather arcane one in that it only works with TCP causing a little headache for UDP.  Instead with CBAC, which involves the `ip inspect` you can achieve the objective ***without*** ACE's involving the `established` keyword.  ACL's can still be used on the outside interface, but they are not required for this specific objective.

Note that CBAC also has the ability to perform application layer gateway (ALG)/fixups to protocols that break through firewall's and NAT boundaries.  In the examples below I'll include some examples.

Easiest way is to define a CBAC inspection set, then apply it in both the `in` and `out` directions on your outside interface.

First defined are generic `tcp` and `udp` to make general tcp and udp traffic work.  Afterward are some ALG's

```
! Define CBAC inspection group in global configuration mode

ip inspect name outside_inspection tcp
ip inspect name outside_inspection udp
ip inspect name outside_inspection ftp
ip inspect name outside_inspection tftp
ip inspect name outside_inspection h323
ip inspect name outside_inspection icmp
ip inspect name outside_inspection pptp

! Enable CBAC on outside interface

interface FastEthernet4
 description outside interface
 ip inspect name outside_inspection in
 ip inspect name outside_inspection out

! ip access-group, ip nat, and others possible as well on FastEthernet4
```